# fail2ban: Creating a custom action that gives parameters to script

Tags: fail2ban

I'm having a few problems to understand the workflow of fail2ban.

My goal is the following action:

name: `pamysql`
used to: exec command with `<name>`, `<failures>`, `<ip>`, ... as parameters

I created `action.d/pamysql.conf` with:

```
actionban = wget -q -O /dev/null server.de/fail2ban/ajax.php?action=ban&jail=<name>&ip=<ip>&failures=<failures>&time=<time>&logpath=<logpath>
```

The `wget` call works, but the parameters like `<name>` and so on don't.

My `jail.conf` looks like this:

```
mta = sendmail
banaction = iptables-multiport
action_mwl = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", ...]
             %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, ...]
             pamysql[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", logpath=%(logpath)s]
action = %(action_mwl)s
```

Can someone explain why the parameters aren't working in `pamysql.conf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. The solution was really simple: The url for the wget call has to go between quotes.

So
`actionban = wget -q -O /dev/null server.de/fail2ban/ajax.php?action=ban&jail=<name>&ip=<ip>&failures=<failures>&time=<time>&logpath=<logpath>`
becomes
`actionban = wget -q -O /dev/null "server.de/fail2ban/ajax.php?action=ban&jail=<name>&ip=<ip>&failures=<failures>&time=<time>&logpath=<logpath>"`